# How do I select only the fields i wanted from multiple Models in Django rest framework?

Tags: json, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

This is my models.py:

```
class UnitOfMeasurement(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    measurement_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    abbreviation=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Product(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True, null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(null=True)
    gstcode = models.ForeignKey(
        GSTCode, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product', null=True)
    unit_of_measurement = models.ForeignKey(
        UnitOfMeasurement, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='category')
    # picture
    objects=ProductManager()

    # select the product where active=true & quantity<0
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So how do I need to code my serializers and views in order to get the data that returns *name, category, brand, model, tag* from **Product Model** and *name* from **Category Model** and also *name* and *measurement_type* from **UnitOfMeasurement Model**?

Answer (score 0):

You can select fields from model in serializer as below example code for **UnitOfMeasurement** and use this serializer for get(retrieve) request.

```
class UnitOfMeasurementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UnitOfMeasurement
        fields = ["name", "measurement_type"]
```

Same thing you can do for rest of models.
Views depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks but the problem is that i need an endpoint that returns the fields together from different models